# VSTO Outlook Addin attached files

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, attachment

I'm working on a VSTO Outlook add-in. One of the actions I want to add is for it to load 2 files from the ATTACHMENTS folder in the project folder:

1. Load the HTML file in the email body
2. Attach the PDF file to the reply.

I've tried a few ways but I can't consistently find the files, even though they are marked with "Copy to output directory"="Copy always"
Am I addressing them correctly in the code below or am I doing something wrong?
Another question, Is there a different between debug and release version that I should handle in the code, in regards, to the files path?

```
            string sPathHtml = @"\ATTACHMENTS\VIA.htm" ;
            string sPathAttachments=  @"\ATTACHMENTS\VIA for RW Pricing team - user guide.pdf";
            string sViaHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sPathHtml);
```

[image: =]

```
public static void AskForViaTicket()
            {
            //GET EMAIL
            EMAIL=getEmail_FirstSelected();

            //VIA HTML
            string startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startupPath);
            string sPathHtml = @"\ATTACHMENTS\VIA.htm" ;
            string sPathAttachments=  @"\ATTACHMENTS\VIA for RW Pricing team - user guide.pdf";
            string sViaHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sPathHtml);

            //REPLY
            Outlook.MailItem reply = EMAIL.ReplyAll();
            reply.HTMLBody = String.Concat("Hi ", EMAIL.SenderName.Split(',')[1], "\n", sViaHtml, "\n", reply.HTMLBody);
            reply.Attachments.Add(sPathAttachments);
            reply.SentOnBehalfOfName = "RW-PricingSupport@iqvia.com";
            reply.CC = "RW-PricingSupport@iqvia.com";
            reply.Display();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the absolute file path instead. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

You may try using the [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=net-6.0) property which returns the fully qualified path of the current working directory. Then you could add subfolders (relative path) to build the full file system path.

Answer (score 1):

Always use absolute path.

If the file are in a folder relative to the location of you addin dll, use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`:

```cs
    //use CodeBase instead of Location because of Shadow Copy.
    string codebase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    var vUri = new UriBuilder(codebase);
    string vPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(vUri.Path + vUri.Fragment);
    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(vPath);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vUri.Host)) directory = @"\\" + vUri.Host + directory;
    string sPathHtml = Path.Combine(directory, @"ATTACHMENTS\VIA.htm");
    string sPathAttachments =  Path.Combine(directory, @"ATTACHMENTS\VIA for RW Pricing team - user guide.pdf");
```